# Retrieving related entities with early bound classes returns null

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011

Some background: I'm writing a custom workflow activity for CRM 2011 in C# and I am using early bound classes generated by CrmSvcUtil.exe. My plugin takes an opportunity as its only input and is supposed to check its related activities, then set a field on the opportunity to denote whether the opportunity needs more follow-up. My problem currently is that whenever I attempt to retrieve the related activities, the result is `null`. Here's the relevant part of my code:
`Opportunity currentOpportunity = (Opportunity) service.Retrieve(context.PrimaryEntityName, context.PrimaryEntityId, new ColumnSet(true));`
`currentOpportunity.Opportunity_ActivityPointers`

I was under the impression that since there is a one-to-many relationship between Opportunity and Activity that this would grab all the relevant activities, but it doesn't seem to be doing that.
I'm still new to CRM and C#, so any insight as to what I'm doing wrong is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using early bound classes, first create data context (in my case it is *XrmServiceContext*). You can retrieve all ActivityPointers where Regarding object is your *opportunity*.

```
OrganizationServiceProxy orgserv;    
using(var xrm = new XrmServiceContext(orgserv))
    {
     //Opportunity currentOpportunity = ...

     IQueryable<ActivityPointer> activityPointers = xrm.ActivityPointerSet.Where(a =>
       a.RegardingObjectId == currentOpportunity.ToEntityReference());
    }
```

ActivityPointer contains ActivityId and ActivityTypeCode if you need some specific activity from this set. More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328379.aspx).

Hope it helps :)